# How to run background process in C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I am completely new to WPF.

I am writing a simple ui for patient monitoring. In the main screen, I have 3 beds i.e. 3 Buttons

I want to run some background process which basically change the background color of each of the button based on some condition. Each button will have its own process before it updates the color.

Answer (score 0):

Multithreading is a large beast to tackle and even more difficult to debug if you don't fully understand the characteristics of multi threaded environments.  Be careful of deadlocks, inadvertently overwriting data in a different thread, and race conditions.  With this said I would suggests 2 things to first explore when writing multithreaded applications.
[background workers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx) and [async functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156513.aspx).

I would start with the background worker and try to send it generics and such, but keep in mind that any changes to the GUI must be done on the same thread that created the GUI (main thread).  So callbacks must be in place which the on completed event of the background worker will allow you to do.